# Is there a way to reject ASP.NET default config files to use single own one?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, configuration

I want to use single config file in my ASP.NET project files.

Is there a **normal adequate** way to stop using default ASP.NET configuration files (e.g. launchSettings.json, appSettings.json...) and apply their settings by my own settings file?

I can't find any settings for these files in empty project.

For newbie in C# I can see these files behind the scene:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `launchSettings.json` is used only for development environments and is quite useful for this case since it provides ability to setup additional things, not only configuration (see [Development and `launchSettings.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0#development-and-launchsettingsjson) section of docs).
2. You can easily clean the configuration sources [included by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-host-configuration-sources) and add your own:

   ```cs
   builder.Configuration.Sources.Clear();
   builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("myConfig.json");
   ```
3. Personally I would recommend to stick to the idiomatic approach provided by the framework which will adhere to [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)